# AFHTTPRequestOperationManager request returns nil while it returns data on browser

Tags: ios, iphone, get, afnetworking

```
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];

    NSString *encodedString = [@"http://public.dawanda.in/category.json" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [manager GET:encodedString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {

         NSLog(@"responseobj %@",responseObject);


     }
         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {

         NSLog(@"RESPONSE: %@", operation.responseString);
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error debugDescription]);
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

     }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is invalid and can't be parsed, if you run the code below you will see the error object states:

`Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Unable to convert data to string around character 1451.) UserInfo=0x7f83dea007a0 {NSDebugDescription=Unable to convert data to string around character 1451.}`

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://public.dawanda.in/category.json";
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (data) {
        NSError *jsonError = nil;
        NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError];
        NSLog(@"error: %@", jsonError);
    }
}];
[dataTask resume];
```

Answer (score 0):

yes Json is invalid but i just found an answer with type of encoding

```
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSString *JsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];//NSASCIIStringEncoding to work round invalid special charcter
        NSData *objectData = [JsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                                                       options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                         error:&error];
```